# Issue when having Symfony form/entity field name 'from'

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a entity with following fields:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="from", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $from;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="to", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $to;
```

I have a symfony form with following fields:

```
->add(
        'from',
        'text',
        array(
            'label' => 'From',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'From whom',
            )
        )
    )->add(
        'to',
        'text',
        array(
            'label' => 'To',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'To whom',
            )
        )
```

When I try to persist and flush the entity after submitting this form it gives the SQL query syntaxt error:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to) VALUES ("from me", "to my wife"' at line 1`

I know this is becase my form field | entity field name!, is there anyway to avoid this error wihout changing my field name 'from'. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: How do you manage your create function (in CRUD action ) ?

Comment: I did something similar and changed the names from **from** and **to** to **source** and **destination**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to escape entity column names and it did the trick:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`from`", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $from;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`to`", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $to;
```

Comment: Keep in mind this could still give you DQL issues if you use that vs. the QueryBuilder.  Is there a reason you don't want to change the column names?  It seems like a much larger headache to keep them as is.

Comment: I will consider changing the names if I run into any problems as you say in the future. Thanks for the insight @JasonRoman !

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to change both of your column names in the database.  The error isn't with Doctrine, but with the fact that both **FROM** and **TO** are MySQL reserved words.  Reserved words would have to be quoted to use them, but why not avoid them altogether?  If you try to run native queries against the database it's going to be really easy to trip up and have something like:

```
SELECT from FROM table;
```

The beauty of Doctrine is that your entity name doesn't have to match your colum name.  So you could have this defined:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="from_whom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $from;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="to_whom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $to;
```

Doctrine abstracts out the MySQL layer, so this code wouldn't even have to change, even after you change the column name:

```
$entity->setFrom($from);
$entity->setTo($to);
```

This might still trip you up in DQL queries though, so I would recommend changing your entity member variables as well.

Comment: Please see my answer and now ti is not throwing errors. Please let me know if there is anything wrong with my approach.